# Azure DevOps - Can we reuse the value of a key in the same variable group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have lots of URL values and their keys. But there is no way to batch import the variables and the "value" controls are also not text boxes in the Variables Group page to perform chrome browser extensions assisted find and replace.

If this is possible, what is the syntax to refer to the key?
As in, I have a variable `App.URL : www.contoso.com`.
I am using the key to substitute value in my next variable like this `Login.URL : $(App.URL)\Login` and this doesn't work.

GitHub link : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3902#issuecomment-489694654

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently available, not sure if it will be.  Can you create a task early in your pipeline that sets the variables you need in subsequent tasks/steps?  This gives you more control as you can store the script along with your source.  You could then use a pipeline variable for the environment you're in and let your script use that to set values appropriately.

See [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-in-script) in the MS docs.

Comment: Correct permalink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible to re-architect your app to concatenate the url strings in the application, what the previous commenter said about creating a simple script to do that for you would be the way to go. Ie:

```
#!/bin/bash
#full login url
fullLoginUrl=$APP.URL\$LOGINSUFFIX
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Login.URL]$fullLoginUrl
```

Otherwise, perhaps playing around with the run time vs compile time variables in YAML pipelines might be worth trying. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax